# Write time stamp for .gpx in R

Tags: r, gps, gpx, sp, rgdal

I am in the process of editing gpx files and need to write the files back to .gpx in order to put them in a GPS unit.  Basically, I am cleaning up some data and removing some track points.  However, when I write the .gpx file, it clears out the timestamp, which makes it very difficult to work with the data later.

I am using the `writeOGR` function from the `rgdal` package to export the file.  An example that can be reproduced with any .gpx file is as follows:

`writeOGR(track, dsn='myfile.gpx', layer="track_points", driver="GPX", dataset_options="GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=yes", "FORCE_GPX_TRACK=true", overwrite_layer = T)`

When you read this back into R using `readOGR("myfile.gpx", layer="track_points)`, the 'time' column is all `NA`.

I am looking for a way to write the original time information to the new .gpx file.

Here is an example workthrough:

`library(rgdal)`

`track<-readOGR(system.file("vectors/test_trk2.gpx", package="rgdal"), layer="track_points")`

`track<-track[is.na(track$time)==F,]  #eliminate NAs from track's time column`

`writeOGR(track, dsn='myfile.gpx', layer="track_points", driver="GPX", dataset_options="GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=yes", "FORCE_GPX_TRACK=true", overwrite_layer = T)`

`track<-readOGR("myfile.gpx", layer="track_points")  #read track back in`

`track@data`

Comment: You can't really deal with time in GIS-like vector data. I'd avoid going through writeOGR for this if you can, you get equivalent of a location-with-other-columns from readOGR so I'd stick with the tabular form until absolutely needed. In a pinch you might keep the "third coordinate" using `sf` but must assume types all the same, putting coordinates in a matrix, so it's a non-starter as well. One way or another you'll have to keep a separate data frame indexed by row to each "spatial location" to use these GIS-y tools.  There's probably a more GPX-focussed package that could help, though.

Comment: Can you supply a sample data and illustrate what you are trying to do, or maybe use a supplied GPX file like the one in the rgdal package: `system.file("vectors/test_trk2.gpx",package="rgdal")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite strange but simple. `readOGR()` still reads the timestamps as you can see with `track$time` but it dosn't write it since it's expecting time to be written in capitals. therefore `track$TIME <- track$time` solves the problem.